# how I could getext from menu item when click in groovy

Tags: java, swing, groovy

I'm trying to get text with this code but appears error

> No such property: menuItem for class: Testgroovy

How i could correct this error

```
import groovy.swing.*
import javax.swing.event.*

new SwingBuilder().edt {
    def fillMenu = { ->
        scripts.removeAll()
String megah=""
        new File('main/groovy').listFiles().each {
 megah=it.name;
            scripts.add(menuItem( ){ action(name:megah, closure:{ println menuItem.getText() })})


        }
    }
    frame(title: 'Testing', size: [800, 600], visible:true,defaultCloseOperation: javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {

        menuBar {
            menu(id:'scripts', text: 'External Scripts')
        }  
    }
    scripts.addMenuListener([ menuCanceled: { e -> ;  println "menuCanceled" },
                              menuDeselected: { e ->  ;  println "menuDeselected"  },
                              menuSelected: { e -> fillMenu() ;  println "menuselected"} ] as MenuListener)

}
```

I USE `println menuItem.getText()` but it does not work

PLease help me

Comment: your code is not complete, please either post the full code or post a runnable example. Not sure if you should write `it` instead of menuItem.

Comment: thi example works is change  println menuItem.getText() for  println  megah  ; but this works with groovy installed and java ; without groovy not works ; the code is complete